# How can I re-download music I bought onto my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-music, library

I was looking for a song today in my music library that I used to listen to all the time because I noticed it would never come on when I shuffled my music. It wasn't in my music library and I used to be able to go to my settings and there was a setting to show music you've purchased from the iTunes Store but wasn't on your device and I could easily go into my music library and press the little cloud button with an arrow and BAM the music would be on my phone again.

Is there a way to still do that without subscribing to Apple Music?.

Answer (score 3):

If you go to you purchases on iTunes Store you can still download your purchases, no apple Music subscription needed.